# Does it make sense to implement clone(), equals() or hashCode() for an abstract class?

Tags: java, clone, abstract-class, equals, hashcode

I am a tutor for Java programming. My students are currently forced (not by me, but by an unclear assignment) to implement [clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29), [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) for an abstract class.

Does it make sense to implement clone(), equals() or hashCode() for an abstract class? Could you give an example where this makes sense?

I could imagine that it makes sense when you have some subclasses x, y, z of an abstract class a. Those subclasses might only differ in the implementation of a method, so you don't need to implement those three methods three times. But I can't imagine any situation where this could be the case.

Comment: `clone` is largely frowned on these days in general, by e.g. [Effective Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=effective+java+clone&source=bl&ots=yYHmNlw3P2&sig=3VM23f9Ygi9jJ1n_tlTM7ypMCeE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dQXrUMbfLOmdiAKcqoGQBQ&ved=0CFsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20clone&f=false).

Comment: Except when you need to clone based on the runtime type, in which case a copy constructor won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't implement `clone()`.

But it makes sense to implement `equals()`, `hashCode()`, and `toString()` to provide the default behavior for all subclasses.  Children can choose to use it if they add no new class members or supplement as needed.

Comment: I'd disagree that it always makes sense to implement hashCode and equals.  Since you are an abstract class, there will always be a subclass.  If the subclass has any instance state at all, your hashCode and equals are worse than helpful -- any two instances that have the same superclass state but differing subclass state will compare equals!  IMO, only implement hashCode and equals if you know what your subclasses must look like, e.g. in AbstractCollection.

Comment: @StevenSchlansker - if you have multiple subclasses, it's usually better to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in the superclass, and mark those methods as `final`. Otherwise, you're likely to break one of the invariants of `equals()` (usually reflexivity). From a theoretical perspective you'd have to wonder why the super/subclass relationship exists at all if the objects do not display some form of intra-comparability.

Comment: @parsifal: Sure, but he's a tutor for Java students.  How much do you want to bet that *any* of the students do it right, given that it isn't an explicit goal of the assignment?  If you aren't going to verify that it will work, leave it out, that's all I'm saying. :-)

Comment: Well argued, Steven.  I like what you're saying and how you said it.

Answer (score 1):

*misread your question and thought you also asked about `toString` - same reasoning applies anyway*

For example, `AbstractCollection` implements `toString()` which basically iterates over the collection and prints it in a user-friendly way.

Direct Subclasses:

```
AbstractList, AbstractQueue, AbstractSet, ArrayDeque, ConcurrentLinkedDeque
```

So all sets, lists and queues share that `toString` method. Each subclass is free to reimplement it if required.

As another example, `equals` is implemented one level lower (in AbstracList/Set etc.).

On the other hand, `clone` is implemented in the final implementation (ArrayList for example), but not in the abstract classes.

Bottom line: sometimes it makes sense but sometimes it doesn't and it should probably not be an obligation applied to all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

1) `clone()` method is very useful, when you need to implement some kind of deep copying of objects, and at the same time you can not use just references to this object, but need new instances of them. So, overriding this method has sense.

2) `equals()` and `hashCode` are two significant important methods, which you have to override when you need a special behaviour for `HashSet/HashMap`, which functioning depends on those methods implementation. So, overriding of them also has sense.

Comment: Clone: ... _Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation._

Comment: Dear @KenKin, I'm talking about overriding this method, when somebody wants do implement *deep* copy of object, instead of using default shallow-copy-implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A major problem with `clone()` is that there are two ways of implementing it, and the proper implementation in a derived class depends upon what its parent class does.

If the parent class and all its ancestors call `super.clone()` until the call reaches `object.clone()`, then the proper thing for a derived class to do is call `super.clone` and then replace any "added" members which encapsulate the mutable states of the targeted objects, but not their identities, with new objects that encapsulate the same states.  If a derived class does not include any added members that encapsulate the states of mutable objects, the derived class need not do anything with `clone` but can simply use the parent's implementation.

The other way for a class to implement `clone()` is to have it include a constructor which accepts an argument of its own type, and chains to a parent constructor which does likewise and then copies all the appropriate properties which are "new" to the type from the passed-in instance to the new one.  An advantage of this approach is that it will work even if the base class implements `clone` this way.  This approach has two disadvantages, however:

1. Every derived type must re-implement clone(), regardless of whether any added members encapsulate mutable state

   Every derived type must implement clone() using this approach, rather than by calling super.clone().

Note that if a type implements `clone()` by calling `super.clone()` but there's an ancestor which does not, the resulting object will end up being of the parent type rather than the derived type--not the way `clone()` is supposed to act.

Answer (score 0):

The  methods clone(), equals() and hasCode() usually have to be implemented in the class implementing that abstract class, because they need the fields, which are not existing in the abstract class.

However there are some situations where equals(), hascode() and probably clone()  makes sense to be implemented in the abstract class. (E.g equals() would make sense in abstract container classes, like Collections, etc.)

For hashCode() and clone() I have more doubt if that makes sense.

Comment: Ah, yes I remember when I was tutor, the task were created by others. It can make sense for container classes, like Collections

Answer (score 0):

Can it make sense?

- To override `clone()` makes sense if the abstract class wants to
  modify the standard behavior of `clone()` especially in respect to
  state that is not accessible to subclasses.
- To override `equals()` and `hashCode()` makes sense if the abstract superclass is enforcing a contract on the behavior of equality. This contract may be specified by itself, or by a superclass or interface it implements.

Is it ever appropriate, i.e. would we ever want to design an abstract superclass to override these?

- As mentioned elsewhere in the answers, the `clone()` mechanism itself is only rarely appropriate. The one appropriate implementation may be to explicilty throw a `CloneNotSupportedException` and making it `final`, and in this way prevent subclasses from implementing `Cloneable`.
- For `equals()` and `hashCode()` the sensible case is also the appropriate case. If an abstract superclass can fulfill the equality contract specifications by itself, it should do so. And it should make the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods `final`, in order to guard against LSP violations. And I'll quote Josh Bloch :

> There is no way to extend an
>   instantiable class and add a value component while preserving the equals
>   contract - *Effective Java 2nd ed.*

Comment: With regard to your last point, why would not derivatives of an `ImmutableShape` abstract class be able to obey the `equals` contract?  The base type might not contain any data members except the dimensions of a bounding rectangle, but its `equals` method would could compare those and also ensure the other object was of the same type.  Derived types would override `equals` to confirm that the base objects match, and that all members added to the derived type also match.  How would that not preserve the `equals` contract?

Comment: The `ImmutableShape` by implementing equals() engages a contract stipulating that two `ImmutableShape` instances are equal if their bounding rectangles are equal. So given an ImmutableShape `a` both `a.equals(new ImmutableShape(a.getBoundingRectangle()){})` and `new ImmutableShape(a.getBoundingRectangle()){}.equals(a)` should return `true`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  If `ImmutableShape` is an abstract class, there won't be any `ImmutableShape` instances.  If the documentation for `ImmutableShape` specifies that any non-broken derived classes must override `Equals` to include any new members, then if `ImmutableTriangle` adds members for its vertices and overrides `Equals` as required, what contract, and with whom, would imply that two instances of `ImmutableTriangle` whose bounding rectangles match should be considered equal?  The only class that can call `ImmutableShape.equals` on an `ImmutableTriangle` is `ImmutableTriangle`...

Comment: ...which would be bound by the documentation of `ImmutableShape` to invoke the base-class implementation of `equals` only as *part* of  its own.

Comment: `new ImmutableShape(a.getBoundingRectangle()){}` is an instance of a subclass of `ImmutableShape` honoring the contract (incidently not adding additional members) and as shown the required symmetric property for `equals()` is violated if it is passed to a subclass of `ImmutableShape` that does require extra members. For more a more detailed explanation I'll refer to item 8 in *Effective Java 2nd ed.*

Comment: How would that be an instance of a subclass?  What subclass?  If one is comparing two instances of the same type, the override of `Equals` should work correctly.  If one compares instances of different types, the base implementation of `equals` would observe that the objects have different types and return `false` on that basis.  If one wanted to allow for a definition of equality which would allow objects of different types to compare equal (e.g. for an `ImmutableRectangle` to compare equal to an `ImmutableSquare`) the base type could provide a transitive `equals` by defining...

Comment: ...a final `equals` method which would, if `other` inherited the same base type, return `(this.equals1(other)*other.equals(this)) >= 2`; virtual `int equals1(object other)` should return 0 if an object could tell the other object was not equal, 1 if it didn't know what the other object was, and 2 if it believed the objects to be equal.  I think it should be pretty obvious that such a definition of `equals` would be transitive for any two objects.